# Spring Security Plugin produces error 500 No thread-bound request found(Maybe because of a Plugin)

Tags: spring, grails

Maybe someone can help me. I am just using plain spring-security-plugin core and executed s2-quickstart command, the command executes fine until you run-app and it produces this error:

> Error 500: Servlet: default URI: /jeepnee/ Exception Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet

Maybe something is amiss with the plugins:

plugins.bubbling=2.1.3
plugins.class-diagram=0.5.2
plugins.cloud-foundry=1.2
plugins.cloud-support=1.0.6
plugins.flash-player=1.4
plugins.grails-ui=1.2.2
plugins.hibernate=1.3.7
plugins.navigation=1.3.2
plugins.resources=1.1.1
plugins.richui=0.8
plugins.swfobject=2.2.1
plugins.tomcat=1.3.7
plugins.yui=2.8.2.1

Can someone enlighten me?

I am stuck with the issue. This is maybe a plugin conflicts with spring security who does web.xml manipulation via runtime too??

Comment: sounds a bit like a configuration mistake, you should post the spring configuration.

Comment: What version of the plugin, and what version of Grails?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the old version of the resources plugin. You need the latest versions of that and Spring Security Core, which use the webxml plugin to order the filter-mapping elements in web.xml appropriately.

Comment: I ran into this issue when upgrading an app from 1.3.7 to Grails 2.0.0 and this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue still persists with the latest plugin versions:

```
runtime ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.1"
runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
```

As a workaround I downgraded as suggested on the [mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-Cloud-Foundry-Plugin-tp4299226p4316053.html) (BuildConfig.groovy)

```
runtime ":spring-security-core:1.2.4"
```

Please vote for this JIRA I've created:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCLOUDFOUNDRY-32

Comment: It is now fixed by adding compile ':webxml:1.4.1' to BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: @MartinMoizard fyi - still had the issue with ssc 1.2.7.3 and grails 2.2.0. Had to add webxml in pom.xml (when building with Maven), then it worked. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Grails 2.2.0 when running the app via maven 'mvn grails:clean grails:run app', while 'grails run-app' alone worked ok, and resolved it as follows:

If you're using Maven, make sure you have this on your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

and in BuildConfig,groovy:

```
runtime ":webxml:1.4.1"
```

That solved the issue for me with Grails 2.2.0.